# How to declare React PropTypes XOR

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I used to write components with multiple configuration For example:

```
ResponsiveTable.PropTypes = {
  width: React.PropTypes.number, //used if widthOffset and minWidth are undefined
  widthOffset: React.PropTypes.number, //used if width is undefined
  minWidth: React.PropTypes.number, //used if width is undefined
};
```

How can I declare props that can be used only if there i snot already other props set?

A [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) option would be usefull. I read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6236):

```
React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.shape({
        width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }),
    React.PropTypes.shape({
        widthOffset: React.PropTypes.number,
        minWidth: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }),  
])
```

Comment: It seems like this would only work as an XOR validation of the properties of, say, an object being passed to your component, as opposed to an XOR validation of the props passed to your component. Am I misunderstanding this and/or do you have more details on how you used this solution to resolve your original question?

Comment: Yes, this simpler solution requires to test a specific prop that contains etiher `width` or `minWidth` and optionally `widthOffset`. It forces you to wrap the properties to test in a specific prop.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the customProp. I got something like that:

```
/**
 * Configure a React type to be usable only if including ot exclufing other props from component
 * @param  {React.PropTypes} propType      current prop type
 * @param  {Array} excludedProps names of the props to exclude
 * @param  {Array} includedProps name of the props to include
 */
function propTypeXOR(propType,excludedProps,includedProps){
  return(props, propName, componentName) =>{
    if(props[propName]){
      if(typeof props[propName] !== propType){
        return new Error("Failed propType: Invalid prop `"+propName+"` of type `"+propType+"` supplied to `"+componentName+"`, expected `number`");
      }else{
        excludedProps.map((excludedPropName) =>{
          if(props[excludedPropName]){
            return new Error("forbidden prop `"+excludedPropName+"` was specified in `"+componentName+"` when using the prop `"+propName+"`");
          }
        })
        if(includedProps){
          includedProps.map((includedPropName) =>{
            if(props[includedPropName]){
              return new Error("required prop `"+includedPropName+"` was not specified in `"+componentName+"` when using the prop `"+propName+"`");
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(excludedProps){
        var error = "";   
        excludedProps.map((excludedPropName) =>{
          if(!props[excludedPropName]){
            error+="`"+excludedPropName+"`,";
          }
        })
        if(error!=""){
          return new Error("required prop `"+propName+"` was not specified in `"+componentName+"`.It is required when props ["+error+"] are not defined.");   
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

ResponsiveTable.propTypes  = {
  width: propTypeXOR("number",["widthOffset","minWidth"]),
  widthOffset: propTypeXOR("number",["width"],["minWidth"]),
  minWidth: propTypeXOR("number",["width"],["widthOffset"])
};
```

It is working: the user must declare either with or widthOffset and minWidth. But I think a more embedded solution will ease declaration and will improve raised error.

I post the need on [react github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6236)

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom property:

```
yourComponent.propTypes = {
  ...
  customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if(checkValid){
      return new Error('validation failed');
    } 
  }
  ...
}
```

this is in react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html